# How to obtain access token after SSO when Salesforce is a service provider?

Tags: integration, single-sign-on, saml

Our users log into Salesforce using the Single Sign-On provided by our Employer. Here Salesforce is a service prover and the Employer's system is the identity provider. The SSO is configured based on SAML Assertion.

Now we want to integrate Salesforce with another system which is also owned by our Employer. This system provides a REST API, which needs to be authenticated using the logged-in user's access token.

The Employer's IT team wants to avoid the Client-Id & Client-Secret based authentication to obtain access token, and they insist on performing user token based authentication (using access token & refresh token). This approach is implemented in one of the mobile app offered by our employer.

Now, how do we obtain the access token from Employer's identity provider after SSO? I have read Salesforce articles about exchanging SAML Assertion to get access token, but I don't know how to get the SAML Assertion after SSO.

Kindly help me out, or clarify incase this ask is not feasible in Salesforce.

Comment: _how do we obtain the access token from Employer's identity provider after SSO_ - that's a question for your Employer's identity provider

Comment: @identigral, that's right, I'm discussing this with the Employer's IT team, but I wanted to understand at a conceptual level, what are expected the expected steps?

Comment: @identigral So far I could understand that I have to exchange the SAML Assertion for the Access Token, assuming there should be a separate API for this, but how do I even obtain the SAML Assertion?

Comment: _have to exchange the SAML Assertion for the Access Token_ - look for another method.